# Windows C++ SDL Eclipse error

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, sdl-2, mingw32

I was following the [tutorial](http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-eclipse-windows/) then when i followed it all the way though but when i went to run the code it gave me the `cannot find -lsdlmain`. I am using the minGW compiler and can use g++ in the command line from any directory. The full console out

```
23:32:34 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Game 1 ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -o "Game 1.exe" "src\\Game 1.o" -lmingw32 -lsdlmain -lsdl2 
b:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsdlmain
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

23:32:35 Build Finished (took 272ms)
```

Comment: Can you post the compilation line?

Comment: the what? sorry i dont know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to the libraries:

```
g++ program.cpp -o executable -I /path/to/includes -L /path/to/libraries -l library1 -l library2
```

I'm guessing g++ doesn't know where to find your sdl libs because you have not added the path with -L

Comment: The SDL libary is in the minGW folder. So SDL lib is in minGW lib folder and the SDL includes are in the minGW include folder

Comment: so sdlmain.lib is in the same directory as mingw32.lib? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: More like i merged the include and lib files of SDL and minGW.